# Linked table in MS Access needs a hyperlink column

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I've recently moved a table from MS Access 2003 into SQL Server 2005.  Then in the Access DB I created a linked table back to the table in SQL Server to replace the original table.

So far everything is working great.  With one exception.  Several of the columns had a datatype of hyperlink in Access but now are VARCHAR(MAX).  From what I can tell from research on-line there is no way to change one of the columns in a linked table back to a hyperlink.

So what I am asking is 1) Does anyone know better?  Can a column in the linked table be changed back to a hyperlink? or 2) Does anyone know of a good workaround?  The user's application seems to require the hyperlink datatype to work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, store your link in the SQL Server text field with the format *"display text#URL#"*, eg. ...

```
Stack Overflow#https://stackoverflow.com/#
```

Then use a form with a text box bound to that text field and set the text box's *Is Hyperlink* property to *Yes*.

That's probably not what you had in mind.  But since SQL Server doesn't offer a counterpart to Access' hyperlink data type, this is the best workaround I've found.

Comment: Great answer.  I'll have my user give it a shot and get back.

Comment: For me, I just wanted a query on a `linked Oracle table` to have hyperlinks. While a query on a `linked Oracle table` can't have hyperlinks, a `datasheet form` can. So your suggestion to use a form was bang on, and even works on datasheet forms.